# How to Prevent Cart from clearing on registration in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If a user adds a product to card, then goes to account page and registers a new account, the product(s) in the cart are automatically removed. How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score -2):

Try following these debugging steps:
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-solving-cart-empty-issue/

Fix 1. Make sure there is no “red alert” under WooCommerce / System Status
Fix 2. Click the following buttons under WooCommerce / System Status / Tools
Fix 3. Check your Theme, WooCommerce & WordPress are using updated, compatible versions
Some premium themes won’t notify you if there is an update available. You have to make sure you’re using the latest, Woo-compatible version. Check with your theme vendor, plugin developers and see if anything has been reported.

For example, you might have updated WooCommerce too soon – sometimes premium plugins/themes require a few days/weeks before they can adapt to the new changes (if major) and become 100% compatible.

Fix 4. Save (flush) your permalinks
Go to WordPress/Settings/Permalinks and click on “save”. This should flush the permalinks and give you a chance to test the cart again.

Fix 5. Check you have no spaces in your checkout end-points
Go to WooCommerce/Settings/Checkout and make sure you have no spaces in your end-points. This happened to a client a while ago and it too me ages to find out (who would think the permalinks had been changed?):

WooCommerce Checkout Endpoints
Fix 6. Properly set up your WordPress cache plugin
Cart and Checkout pages should not be cached – if your WordPress cache plugin is for some reason caching WooCommerce pages, your cart will probably show as empty. Make sure to select a WooCommerce-compatible cache plugin

Also: ask your hosting to disable or properly set up server cache
Some hosts have their own cache system and this is sometimes applied to your website by default. Create a ticket or give them a quick call to find out if they have anything like that and if they can disable that as soon as possible.

For example: WPEngine uses its own cache. This might affect your WooCommerce Cart. Please contact support so they can create a caching exception list for WooCommerce and/or ajax files

Fix 7. Disable all plugins but WooCommerce
This is a typical troubleshooting operation. Disable all plugins and see if the Cart is back functioning. If YES, reactivate one plugin at a time and test the Cart again. As soon as you find the “guilty” plugin – yay! – time to substitute that plugin or see if there is an update available!

Fix 8. Try switching to a default WordPress Theme (e.g. TwentySixteen)
This is to prove the error is not theme-related. You won’t lose any content if you switch between themes, so don’t worry. If the error goes away, then check with your theme developers and report the bug